# MySQL join if address value not equal default

Tags: php, mysql

Data:

```
[ID] => 4
[Create_date] => 2017-10-07
[Client] => 17
[Address] => default
[GST] => Regular
[Rate_group] => D
[Sales_man] => 0
[CGST] => 91.12
[SGST] => 91.12
[IGST] => 0
[Discount] => 10
[Total] => 1397.25
[LR_number] => 0
[LR_date] => 0000-00-00
[Transport] => 5
[Transport_branch] => default
[Remark] => Hi, my name is Rushabh Shah.
[Payment_mode] => Cash
[Status] => Open
[Customer_name] => Rushabh Infotech
[Transport_name] => Shah Infotech
```

MYSQL Query:

```sql
SELECT `sale`.*, 
       `customer`.`english_company_name`  AS `Customer_name`, 
       `transport`.`english_company_name` AS `Transport_name` 
FROM   `sale` 
       LEFT JOIN `customer` 
              ON `customer`.`id` = `sale`.`client` 
       LEFT JOIN `transport` 
              ON `transport`.`id` = `sale`.`transport`
```

MySQL join with `Transport_branch` if `Transport_branch != 'default'`. Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: `Mysql join with transport_branch if Transport_branch != 'default'. Anyone can please tell me How can I achieve this.` Not You can't conditional join.. and your question isn´t clear

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case when

```
SELECT `sale`.*, 
       `customer`.`english_company_name`  AS `Customer_name`, 
       `transport`.`english_company_name` AS `Transport_name` ,
        case when `transport`.`transport_branch` = 'default' 
                    THEN  `transport`.`english_company_name`
                    ELSE `transport_brach`.`transport_btanch__company_name`
        end AS my_transport_name
FROM   `sale` 
       LEFT JOIN `customer` 
              ON `customer`.`id` = `sale`.`client` 
       LEFT JOIN `transport` 
              ON `transport`.`id` = `sale`.`transport`
       LEFT JOIN `transport_branch` 
           ON `transport_branch`.`id` = `transport`.`id`
```